# How to test for Empty array value in Unirest json Response

Tags: groovy, unirest, jira-rest-java-api

I have the following code snipet used in Jira Script Runner cloud

```
String _userId
def result = get(graph_base_user_url + "?")
         .header("Authorization","Bearer " + AuthToken )
         .queryString("\$filter","mail eq '$userEmail'")
         .asJson()
        
        if (result.getStatus().toString() =="200")
        {
            **if (result.getBody().value){  // <<<<< is Value is not empty ???
              _userId=result.getBody().value[0].id    
            }** 
            else
            _userId="-1" // user does not exist
                                
        }
        // user ID not found : error 404
        if (result.getStatus().toString()=="404")
         _userId="User not found"
```

This code is returning in the result.getBody() the following output

{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users","value":[]}

What I am trying to achieve is to test if the value array of the response is empty or not and if not empty I need to fetch the first element item as value[0].Id, but I could not get it correctly

How can I define my code in BOLD above to perform my correct test ?
Error I get from my code is : " Value is not a property of JsonNode object

Thanks for help
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from official doc http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#responses

```
String result = Unirest.get("http://some.json.com")
                       .asJson()
                       .getBody()
                       .getObject()
                       .getJSONObject("car")
                       .getJSONArray("wheels")
                       .get(0)
```

so, something like this should work for you:

```
def a = result.getBody().getObject().getJSONArray("value")
if(a.length()>0) _userId = a.get(0).get("id")
```